# java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay, liferay-6

I am displaying a list of items with links in my xhtml page. When I click my "back to previous page" button from that link, I basically reset the flags in my bean to indicate to the xhtml which page to display, and reload the list of links from my database.

When I click the same link (or any other link for that matter) in this new page, I get this error:

```
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: javax.faces.FacesException: 
   Unexpected error restoring state for component with id A8351:j_idt7:j_idt10:j_idt59.  
   Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;.
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseActionImpl.execute(BridgePhaseActionImpl.java:105)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:81)
        at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.processAction(GenericFacesPortlet.java:152)
    at com.ncs.portalcity.lfe.faces.bridge.FacesPortlet.processAction(FacesPortlet.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component
with id A8351:j_idt7:j_idt10:j_idt59.  Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;.
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:284)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1589)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.execute(LifecycleWrapper.java:35)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseActionImpl.execute(BridgePhaseActionImpl.java:77)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior.restoreState(AjaxBehavior.java:459)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreBehaviors(UIComponentBase.java:2184)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreBehaviorsState(UIComponentBase.java:2151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1571)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:276)
    ... 162 more
```

If I refresh the page and try again, there are no issues. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---- Edit ----

Just in case anyone else using liferay has this problem, I just added these lines in my pom.xml and it's ok now :) Thanks so much BaluC!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.21</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.21</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known Mojarra issue and already reported as [issue 2041](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2041) which is fixed in Mojarra 2.1.12.

So, just upgrading your JSF libraries to at least Mojarra 2.1.12 should do. It's currently already at 2.1.26, with many more fixes related to state management and likes as compared to 2.1.12.