# Mojarra upgrade

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss 6.1.0.Final and I had to upgrade Mojarra version from 2.0 to 2.1.24 in order to solve problem reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719592/java-lang-classcastexception-javax-faces-component-stateholdersaver-cannot-be-c).
This upgrade was sucessful, but it introduced [another problem](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2973).
So I'm trying to upgrade to latest version of Mojarra, which is 2.1.28. This is raising the following error when trying to start the server:

```
16:44:06,815 INFO  [AbstractJBossASServerBase] Server Configuration:

    JBOSS_HOME URL: file:/home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/
    Bootstrap: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
    Common Base: $JBOSS_HOME/common/
    Common Library: $JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/
    Server Name: default
    Server Base: $JBOSS_HOME/server/
    Server Library: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/
    Server Config: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/
    Server Home: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/
    Server Data: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/data/
    Server Log: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/log/
    Server Temp: $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp/

16:44:06,817 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"]
16:44:07,859 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_20,Sun Microsystems Inc.
16:44:07,859 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
16:44:07,859 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 16.3-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
16:44:07,859 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Linux 2.6.38-10-generic-pae,i386
16:44:07,860 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 6.x Runtime -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/lib/endorsed -Djava.library.path=/home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/native -Dlogging.configuration=file:/home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/logging.properties -DAMBIENTE=desenvolvimento -DFILE_PATH=/mnt/imagens -DPDF_FILE_PATH=/home/cassio/projetos/app-pdfs -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
16:44:07,895 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
16:44:10,509 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
16:44:10,979 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 4 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-2.1.26, Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]
16:44:13,067 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostParse: name=vfs:///home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/my-app.war state=Parse mode=Manual requiredState=PostParse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///home/cassio/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/my-app.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null attachment
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.addAttachment(AttachmentsImpl.java:72) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.TrackingMutableAttachments.addAttachment(TrackingMutableAttachments.java:131) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractDeploymentUnit.addAttachment(AbstractDeploymentUnit.java:334) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.attachments.helpers.AbstractMutableAttachments.addAttachment(AbstractMutableAttachments.java:44) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.attachments.helpers.AbstractMutableAttachments.addAttachment(AbstractMutableAttachments.java:67) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.jsf.deployer.JSFImplManagementDeployer.deploy(JSFImplManagementDeployer.java:281) [:1.0.3]
    at org.jboss.jsf.deployer.JSFImplManagementDeployer.deploy(JSFImplManagementDeployer.java:56) [:1.0.3]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 43 more
```

The same happens if trying to upgrade to 2.1.27, 2.1.26 and 2.1.25. Any ideas on what may be the problem?

**NOTE**: to perform the upgrades I followed the steps of section "Jboss 6 upgrading JSF" in [here](http://entjavastuff.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/migrating-to-jboss-51-from-jboss-42x.html).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on Eclipse side; it was corrupted. I switched back to an old ".metadata" backup and it got back to work.